# How can I make this function iterate through both of ranges?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

So I have been trying to build a function to increment the cells using a `For loop`

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(N$10>=PivotTabel!$L5;N$10<=PivotTabel!$M5);"1";"0.5");"X") & 
IF(AND(N$10>=Sheet1!$L125;N$10<=Sheet1!$M125);"yes";"n") & 
IF(AND(N$10>=Sheet1!$L126;N$10<=Sheet1!$M126);"yes";"n") & 
IF(AND(N$10>=Sheet1!$L127;N$10<=Sheet1!$M127);"yes";"n")
```

This formula is to check if a date is  between a date period ( for example to check if 01.01.2020 is between 02.08.2019 and 20.02.2020 if True in the first case i print "1" and other cases i print "yes").
As you can see above is the formula that i need to write in VBA to iterate through a specified number of cells which are **$L125:$L139** for one column, and the other column **$M125:$M139**

I wrote the function below but it gives me **#VALUE!**

```
Function Date_Increment(MaxCount As Integer) As String
' This function does incrementation of date ranges
Dim Result As String
Static i As Integer
i = 125
Dim cell As Range

'MaxCount is the number times to iterate just to test 
'My idea is to use the function COUNT("L125:L139") to return the number of cells that are not blank

For Each i In MaxCount 

    '  this is the cell i want to run formula in  

    Range("GUI!D12").Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(AND(D$10>=PivotTabel!$L5;D$10<=PivotTabel!$M5);""1"";""0.5"");""X"") & IF(AND(D$10>=Sheet1!$L" & i & ";D$10<=Sheet1!$M" & i & ");""yes"";""n"")"
    Result = Range("GUI!D12").Formula
i = i + 1
Next cell
'Next j
DateRange_Increment
End Function
```

**My question is : How can I make this function iterate through both of ranges? Or If there is a simple solutions using only formulas i would also use it. In addition please check if i have errors in the function.**

Any help i would really appreciate it.

Comment: What is the line `DateRange_Increment` (2nd from the end) supposed to do? By the way, this very much seems like an XY problem.

Comment: call for the function , is it correct?

Comment: Okay i removed it, but still giving the same error.

Comment: You can't do `Range("GUI!D12").Formula = ....` inside a UDF that you're calling from a cell... there are several issues with your current code, but I suspect if you explain in broad terms what you're trying to do, we may be able to propose an alternative.

Comment: Okay, i want to optimize this formula ```=IFERROR(IF(AND(D$10>=PivotTabel!$L5;D$10<=PivotTabel!$M5);"1";"0.5");"X") & IF(AND(D$10>=Sheet1!$L125;D$10<=Sheet1!$M125);"yes";"n") & IF(AND(D$10>=Sheet1!$L126;D$10<=Sheet1!$M126);"yes";"n") & IF(AND(D$10>=Sheet1!$L127;D$10<=Sheet1!$M127);"yes";"n") & IF(AND(D$10>=Sheet1!$L128;D$10<=Sheet1!$M128);"yes";"n")```

i dont want to write too many ifs; Is there any way either  using formulas or VBA?